# How to convert a binary data into c_ubyte_Array_64 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

How to convert ` b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01' c_ubyte_Array_64 in python. I could find any resources only so any help would really appreciated.

I have to send this message which should be of type c_ubyte_Array_64

```
import ctypes
messages = {
    "RESET": b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01',
}

ba = bytearray(messages['RESET'])
```

I tried it  in the above manner  but it  gives me this error

```
TypeError: expected c_ubyte_Array_64 instance, got bytearray
```

Comment: Can you provide an expected outcome example?

Comment: please add this as answer

Comment: The code displayed does not produce the error specified.  `ctypes` is not being used at all.

Comment: @rohithsantosh: it would be a good idea to also add the line (and other possible dependent ones) where you're trying to use *ba*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listing [[Python.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

> ```py
> >>> import ctypes as ct
> >>>
> >>> messages = {
> ...     "RESET": b"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01",
> ... }
> >>>
> >>> UByteArr64 = ct.c_ubyte * 64  # Create the array type
> >>>
> >>> arr = UByteArr64(*messages["RESET"])  # Create an array instance (by unpacking the byte sequence)
> >>>
> >>> arr
> <__main__.c_ubyte_Array_64 object at 0x0000015C81D74C40>
> >>> arr[0:16]
> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
> >>>
> >>>
> >>> # Or, in one line:
> >>> (ct.c_ubyte * 64)(*messages["RESET"])
> <__main__.c_ubyte_Array_64 object at 0x0000015C81DBA240>
> ```